# Tizen: Sensor data calibration and recorded timestamp

Tags: accelerometer, tizen, gyroscope, calibration

I record sensor data from the Samsung Watch3 Wearable. In particular, I collect accelerometer, gravity and gyroscope data, using the SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER, SENSOR_GRAVITY and SENSOR_GYROSCOPE respectively.
I found out that SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER provides already calibrated data. Should I calibrate manually the Gyroscope data?

My second question concerns the timestamp of each data sample recorded from the device.
Here is an example of the time the data I collect from the Gyroscope:

```
       x    y     z          time
474  6.72 -5.46  2.87 2021-06-30 15:17:51.226
475  7.98 -3.15 -1.68 2021-06-30 15:17:51.247
476 -0.49  3.15 -0.84 2021-06-30 15:17:51.249
477  0.70  2.10 -0.63 2021-06-30 15:17:51.266
478  1.75 -0.70 -1.82 2021-06-30 15:17:51.268
```

I can understand that eg. 15:17:51.226 the Gyroscope reads multiple recordings, but it keeps one. Does anyone know if these metrics are the first or the last of each time, that the sensor captures?

Answer (score 1):

1. Gyroscope data is calibrated too.

   In the public Tizen site, there are two types of gyroscope.
   "Gyroscope" and "Uncalibrated gyroscope"
   (https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/location-sensors/device-sensors/)
   "Gyroscope" sensor gives the calibrated data already.
2. I don't know how to understand that Gyroscope reads multiple recordings, but in my opinion, it reads a data at each time.

   If you read the sensor_event_s structure, it give a data with a timestamp.
   (https://docs.tizen.org/iot/api/latest/tizen-iot-headed/structsensor__event__s.html)

   Also in Tizen API, you can set a interval of update of sensor value and its minimum value is usually 10ms.
   So, maybe the sensor gives only a data each timestamp.